# Can Kamailio pass through http request to asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, kamailio

I am attempting to send http request from the tool TRYITJsSIP through kamailio to asterisk, however, kamailio returns an error on tcp_read_req (state 7; bad request, no other serror given).  Is there a setting I need to allow http packets to pass through kamailio. Note: It does work when I use a tool like MicroSIP or LinPhone.

Thank you

Comment: why you want use sip proxy instead of http proxy?

Comment: All of our calls are required to go through asterisk, and we currently have kamailio in front of asterisk for for sip calls.  My requirement is to determine if I can send wetRTC through kamailio into asterisk's ws port.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: WebRTC is not http. Yes, kamailio can handle webrtc and can do webrtc to sip convertion(recomended) for asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers (at least modern browsers) in which WebRTC apps execute require, in order to allow sharing audio and video devices, connections with servers to be done in a secure way. In web, you could use of WSS. Asterisk and Kamailio support WSS (WebSockets Secure) as transport for SIP.

It is possible (I have done it) to configure chan_pjsip in Asterisk to use  WSS as transport (chan_sip also can be configured in that way, but I have not yet experience in WSS with chan_sip). Kamailio has the [WebSocket module](https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/devel/modules/websocket.html) that also allows it to manage WSS SIP connections. I have used a fork of JsSIP (SIP.js), but it is completely arguable and you may have your own selection criteria.

Thus, you can connect

Web app WebRTC -> WSS -> Asterisk

or

Web app WebRTC -> WSS -> Kamailio -> UDP -> Asterisk

or, of course, whatever architecture you feel comfortable with. The only thing  to have into account is that connections between browser and SIP Proxy are to be done in a secure way (you could use also DTLS-SRTP because Asterisk and Kamailio support it and both are natively supported by WebRTC, but, once again, I have not tested it myself).

Comment: Thank you very much for this detail...it really is appreciated!

Comment: I have attempted using sipML5 instead of tryit but I have not been able to figure out the configuration.  I am having kamailio listen on port 15000 so i changed my sipML5 to wss://21.1.1.32:15000/  I see the request coming through to kamalio but I just see a disconnected message from sipML5.  I have tried many configurations but just can't get a connection.

Comment: I would suggest testing firstly without kamailio (WebRTC - WSS - Asterisk). I can confirm you that it works both with sipml5 and sip.js using chan_pjsip. Then you could concentrate yourself in configuring kamailio. If not possible, I would read [this presentation](https://es.slideshare.net/crocodilertc/sip-over-websocket-on-kamailio), [this tutorial](http://nil.uniza.sk/sip/kamailio/configuring-kamailio-4x-websocket) and [this conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/2600hz-dev/UeUqXO94zhc)